# What type of siddhi is it where one can create one's own world or loka?

Tags: siddhi

Vishwamitra created his own heavenly universe after being denied acess to Trisanku to devaloka. Many buddhists also say they have experienced pureland,which must have been created through siddhi of a buddhist yogi.Bon practicioners also have their own heavens or purelands.

Yogis can also create Jñāna ganja/gyanganj through their powers,wich exist in the astral realm.

More on jñāna ganja/Gyan ganj  can be read at [here](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=1424&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)

What type of siddhi is this?

edit:maybe buddhist bodhisattvas have merely attained a baindava body wich is immortality but that this is not moksha.the purelands they attain are created through the siddhi of Prāṇa Jyoti wich allows full mastery over the elements,and this is why buddhas and other ascended masters can create their own lokas through this siddhi in the etheric plane or planes.

this is also what allows hindu siddhas to create realms in the astral.

Comment: No siddhi is required. Anyone can do it. Just lie down and close your eyes.

Comment: @Lokesh Care to explain how?

Comment: "wich must have been created through siddhi of a buddhist yogi" no this is not the case. Why do you draw this conclusion?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto He is probably talking about dreaming.

Comment: Ashta siddhis like Prakamya, Ishitva,Vashitva etc., https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8265/16530

Comment: I think its  the siddhi of Prāṇa Jyoti wich allows full mastery over the elements with preservation,creation,destruction etc.