# What's the difference between a Māyāví & Siddha?

Tags: scripture, siddhi, maya

*Śrī Kṛṣṇā* at various instances in the *Mahābhārata* showed his various divine opulences in myriad ways. But, several people used the word *Māyāví* for dismissing it as something *tāmasī* or non-divine. Moreover, generally, as far as I understand, the word *Māyāví* is mostly used in a negative connotation only.

Also, there's a concept of a divine person *Siddha* (here to be taken as, one in possession of the eight great 
perfections - *[Aṣṭa Siddhīs](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/what-is-ashta-siddhi-and-nav-nidhi?r=SearchResults)*  ).

Generally if one looks explicitly in material sense, both, a *Māyāví* &  a *Siddha* can portray or exhibit the "miraculous activities" that  are considered supernatural or not achievable for a normal human in any *Yuga* perhaps.

So, how may one distinguish between these two, 
a *Māyāví* &  a *Siddha*? 
Does scriptures talk about this difference / indifference, in any way?