# What is the objective of human life?

Tags: philosophy, life

According to Hinduism, What is the objective of human life? Further what should be our ultimate goal?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I was about to flag this question as duplicate of [What is the ultimate goal of Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/what-is-the-ultimate-goal-of-hinduism). But I din't do for 2 reasons: (1) The old question is more focused on the Hinduism perspective rather than general perspective. (2) The accepted answer doesn't really answer this question.

Comment: @iammilind Well, first of all, in this site everything should be focused on the Hinduism perspective.  Second of all, yeah, the accepted answer isn't necessarily the best, but Swami Vishwananda's answer looks good.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I agree [Swami Vishwananda's answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/5149/1049) is more accurate. May be it's not accepted due to poor formatting.